# How to make a hyperlink show in a different line

Tags: javascript

Hi i am making a books website and im trying to add a hyperlink using href but it comes up in the same line is there any way to make it to show in a different line?[here is how it shows up right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o2rs.png)

```
const petsData = [{
  name: "Story Book",
  species: "Jean Lumier",
  favFoods: ["wet food", "dry food", "<strong>any</strong> food"],
  birthYear: 2016,
  href: "https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png",
  photo: "https://nice-assets.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/smart_templates/e639b9513adc63d37ee4f577433b787b/assets/wn5u193mcjesm2ycxacaltq8jdu68kmu.jpg"
},
{
  name: "Barksalot",
  species: "Dog",
  href:"https://www.amazon.in/Redmi-9A-2GB-32GB-Storage/dp/B08696XB4B/ref=gbph_img_m-2_0ec7_a9c5af13?smid=A23AODI1X2CEAE&pf_rd_p=cbec21a0-e969-48e2-8697-caf621220ec7&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=1389401031&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_r=7N08PRZ1WREYVED1R3Q4",
  birthYear: 2008,
  photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/dog-1.jpg"
},
{
  name: "Meowsalot",
  species: "Cat",
  favFoods: ["tuna", "catnip", "celery"],
  birthYear: 2012,
  photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/cat-1.jpg"
}



];


//empty space thing (ㅤ)


function petTemplate(pet) {
  
return `
<div class ="image-grid">
   <div class="animal">
   
      <img class="pet-photo " src="${pet.photo}">
     
      
      <div class="olay">
      
      
      <h2 class="pet-name">${pet.name}
      //href here
      <h1 class="species">${pet.species}
      <a href= ${pet.href}> Read Reviews</a>
      
      
      
      
       <div></div></div>
      </div>
   </div>

  
`;
}
```

(Sorry english is not my main language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several simple ways to achieve this:

Perhaps the easies it to wrap your link in a div

`<div><a href= ${pet.href}> Read Reviews</a></div>`

Another option is to have `br` tag before the link `<a href= ${pet.href}> Read Reviews</a>`

The most standard way to achieve your task might be to use flexbox in your CSS style read more about flexbox here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class ="image-grid">
   <div class="animal">
   
      <img class="pet-photo " src="${pet.photo}">
     
      
      <div class="olay">
      
      
      <h2 class="pet-name">${pet.name} </h2>
      //href here
      <h1 class="species">${pet.species} </h1>
      <a href= ${pet.href}> Read Reviews</a>
      
      </div>
      
      
       
      </div>
   </div>
```

Or you can wrap `h2`, `h1` and the `a` tag in its own div

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags (with `</h1>` and `</h2>`, not with `</div>`!)